# How do I write a method that assigns a random number to a list of users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I need to create an application with MVC architecture. I need to generate random numbers 5 digits for users of my app. I mean, this method put on controller user , generate the numbers and show it in a view like a list (user + numbers sign) like a password

Do you have any idea? sorry for my English. 
I need it for a test

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult GenerateNumbers( User user)
{

    Random rand = new Random();
    int numero = rand.Next(1, 10000);
    return View();
    var nuevoCodigo = new User
    {
        Name = user.Name,
        Code = numero,        
    };
    db.Users.Add(nuevoCodigo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your action to this:

```
public ActionResult GenerateNumbers( User user)
    {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int numero = rand.Next(10000, 99999);

        var nuevoCodigo = new User
        {
            Name = user.Name,
            Code = numero,

        };
        db.Users.Add(nuevoCodigo);
        //You should commit your context here also  
        return View(db.Users); // Pass user list as your model to view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want always 5 digit code or can be from 1 to 5 digit.

```
public ActionResult GenerateNumbers( User user)
{
  //first approach
  var nuevoCodigo = new User
  {
    Name = user.Name,
    Code = GenerateCode()    
  };
  //second approach
  var nuevoCodigo = new User
  {
    Name = user.Name
    Code =GenerateCode(5)
  };
  db.Users.Add(nuevoCodigo);
  return View(db.Users);
}

private int GenerateCode()
{
  Random rand = new Random();
  return rand.Next(10000, 99999);//change 10000 to 1 if code should be 1 digit
}


public int GenerateCode(int length)
{
   Random random = new Random();
   const string chars = "0123456789";
   string code =  new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
   return Convert.ToInt32(code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important part is returning the view with `User` viewmodel then format generated code as 5-digit code with [numeric format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-decimal-d-format-specifier), you can try this approach:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GenerateNumbers(User user)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numero = rand.Next(1, 100000);
    var nuevoCodigo = new User
    {
        Name = user.Name,
        Code = numero       
    };

    using (var db = new UserEntities())
    {
        db.Users.Add(nuevoCodigo);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // return view page with assigned viewmodel properties
    return View(nuevoCodigo);
}
```

**View**

```
@* using 'D' format specifier to show the value, including zeros *@
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Code, "{0:D5}", null)
```

NB: [`Random.Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx)'s `maxValue` argument  is **exclusive upper bound** of returned random numbers (not counted as part of number generation unlike `minValue` which is inclusive), hence if you want to specify number between `00001` to `99999`, the `maxValue` should be `100000`.

Simple Demo: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AFAc4u)

Comment: thnks it workd but i cant assign numbers to all users who already exist

Comment: Can you explain "can't assign numbers to all users who already exist"? If you want to assign number for existing users, you can perform `Where` LINQ query to create user list, set the number and call `SaveChanges()` later.

Comment: yes i need that. I mean assing number for  all existing users

Comment: Do you want to assign them in same or different controller? You can try with this LINQ query: `var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == [assigned user ID])`, then assign `user.Code = numero` and call `db.SaveChanges()` afterwards.